# Is singleton a algorithm and is it covered in knuth's

Tags: algorithm, knuth

I owned a copy of Game Programming Gems a while ago and used Singletons in an application. I wanted to know if Singletons are considered an algorithm and if not what are they?. Secondly, I am going to most likely purchase Knuth's algorithm book and wanted to know if methodologies like Singletons are covered in it?

Comment: Singleton is a design pattern. Design patterns are not the same thing as algorithms.

Comment: Knuth doesn't cover programming methodologies or design patterns in his books.

Comment: Thanks for removing the downvotes but I still have not got an explanation as to why it was downvoted.

Comment: No one removed the downvotes. Someone else gave it an upvote, and they cancelled out. Whoever gave the downvote will never see your question, so there's no way to know why he did it.

Comment: But I suggest you go to the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and read about how to ask a proper question here.